# Executing a Complex Aggregation Query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to execute a complex Aggregation query in MongoDB against 2 collections. (2.3 Million docs & 500K documents) I've been using [Studio3T](https://studio3t.com) to build the aggregation query. However it seems to run forever.
So I tried the query in [MongoDBCompass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) and it seems to give a timeout after few seconds of running the query.
Afterwards I tried this in MongoAtlas & it seems to work without a issue and result was generated within minutes.
I've Tried mongoShell as well, but it keeps hanging without any result for more than a hour.

Please note that Aggregation query used was same in all platforms/softwares hence it worked on atlas without a issue query seems not a issue.

Are there any alternatives to get the results of the aggregation exported to either a new collection/csv or a JSON for a task of this magnitude?

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      scoringMethod: "INSTRUCTOR",
      assignmentStatus: "PUBLISHED",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "submission",
      let: {
        assignmentId: "$_id",
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$_id.assignmentId",
                    "$$assignmentId",
                  ],
                },
                {
                  $or: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$status",
                        "SUBMITTED",
                      ],
                    },
                    {
                      $eq: ["$status", "SCORED"],
                    },
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$status",
                        "SCORED_PUBLISHED",
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "submissions",
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      assignmentId: "$_id",
      submissionCount: {
        $size: "$submissions",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      submissionCount: {
        $gt: 0,
      },
    },
  },
]
```

Comment: I don't think your conclusion is necessarily correct. Many of the client interfaces/tools inject limits on the pipelines written by the users prior to sending them to the database for execution. This is similar to how Compass added a timeout. So you may not be comparing apples to apples here. Regardless I'm not sure there is enough information here to assist in any case. What does the complex pipeline look like? What are the indexes and explain output for it? How fast are you expecting the operation to run?

Comment: Do you have a [_compound index_](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-compound/) on `scoringMethod` and `assignmentStatus`?  Do you have an index on `_id.assignmentId`?  Do you have an index on `status`?  Have you tried simplifying `"$lookup"` with `"localField": "_id", "foreignField": "_id.assignmentId", "pipeline": [{"$match": {"status": {"$in": ["SUBMITTED", "SCORED", "SCORED_PUBLISHED"]}}}]`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I only have a index on _id field. Let me check with above changes. tia